# Python GUI login Database

Tags: python, sql, database, authentication, sqlite

I am having issues regarding database in my python login form.
I am unable to fetch data by `SQL` query 
I import sqlite3

1. Create table columns and username and password
2. Successfully insert the value into the table
3. When I fetch it gives me a syntax error

   `d1 = c1.execute("Select username form table where username =  variable")`

It works when I use `username = 'Abhishek'` in the above query.

Comment: Do you mind showing an MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: aren't you missing the ' to indicate your variable should be considered a string? Also isn't there a preparedStatement kind of thing in python

Comment: thanks i understand now

Comment: sorry i didn't know about the MCVE..

Answer (score 0):

## try like this:

```
#import sqlite3 module
import sqlite3

#Db connection
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = db.cursor()

#Create table
cursor.execute(
            '''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS username (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            age TEXT NOT NULL,
            phone TEXT);
            '''
        )

 #Insert your name
 cursor.execute(
        '''
        INSERT INTO username (name, age, phone)
        VALUES ("Abhishek", "18", "+123456789")
        '''
    )


#Commit previous table creation
db.commit()

#Select all from username table where name column is like 'Abhishek'
myname = 'Abhishek'
sql = f"SELECT * FROM username WHERE name='{myname}'"
#Alternative you can prepare sql like this, attention in quotes('var') aroud myname variable
sql = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE name='{}'".format(myname)
cursor.execute(sql)
#Get all results
result = cursor.fetchall()
for i in result:
    print(i)
```